# Why doesn't picture show with UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

#### What to do

I hope to show picture and message when user use UIPickerView.
Now it can show message with UIPickerview, However picture isn't shown.
I wanted to use array, but I can't use.
That's why I wrote code and make error.

#### What happened ?

I tried to make code which is for showing picture when UIPickerView is selected.the app is done and shown. However,picture isn't shown.

#### Source

//  ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var introduce: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageV: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView!
    let names = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
    let message = [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
        "E"]


    //let picture = ["A.png","B.png","C.png","D.png","E.png"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Delegate Setting
        pickerview.delegate = self
        pickerview.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    var rownumber = 0

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    func pickerView1(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    -> Int {
        rownumber = row
        return rownumber

    }


    // What UIPickerView shows at first time
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    titleForRow row: Int,
                    forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return names[row]
    }


    func readimg(rimg:Int) -> UIImageView {
        if rownumber == 0 {

            let imageV1 = UIImage(named:"A.png")
            imageV.image = imageV1

        }
        if rownumber == 1 {

            let imageV1 = UIImage(named:"B.png")
            imageV.image = imageV1

        }
        if rownumber == 2 {

            let imageV1 = UIImage(named:"C.png")
            imageV.image = imageV1

        }
        if rownumber == 3 {

            let imageV1 = UIImage(named:"D.png")
            imageV.image = imageV1

        }
        if rownumber == 4 {

            let imageV1 = UIImage(named:"E.png")
            imageV.image = imageV1

        }

        return imageV

    }

    // When Row Of UIPickerView is selected
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    didSelectRow row: Int,
                    inComponent component: Int) {
       introduce.text  = message[row]

        // If I write it sentence, it has error.
       readimg(rimg: Int)
       // Error Code (Editor placeholder in source file/Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to expected argument type 'Int')


    }



}
```

#### What did I?

I check all error and solve.

Comment: When and where do you want the images to appear? Do want them in each row of the picker view?

Comment: There is UI Image View. If user selects picker view, a picture which is choose by function appears . I hope to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass integer value to `readimg(rimg: Int)` method. So change it to pass row value inside `pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` method.

So it become like this.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
   introduce.text  = message[row]
   readimg(rimg: row)
}
```

In addition to that, `readimg` method does not need to return `UIImageView` if you decide to assign `imageV` value inside that function, so you might want to change its method signature to return void.

```
func readimg(rimg:Int) {
  // Your method implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you for apply. I wish I could change its signature to void. However I don't know how to change. Could you show me example code?